# Passing POST variable into two pages back and forth

Tags: php, session

I have a scenario here in which I am confused to solve. So here is the matter,

1. I have a PHP page with the project selector that gives the value into monitorIndex.php
2. And in the monitorIndex.php im using that given value with this

   if(isset( $_POST['cd-dropdown'])) $_SESSION['cd-dropdown'] = $_POST['cd-dropdown'];

in which I use $_POST['cd-dropdown'] as the value used everywhere

now my question is, when user click on the navigation menu to go to a page called monitorTable.php, how do I still use the $_POST['cd-dropdown'] ? and how to make variable alive when user navigate out from that page and go back to monitorIndex.php and keeping the $_POST['cd-dropdown'] alive

thank you so much

Comment: since you already assigned it in a session variable, `$_POST['cd-dropdown']`'s values are inside `$_SESSION['cd-dropdown']`. dont forget to add `session_start()` on your php pages

Comment: State variables like this should be added as a query parameter to URLs. Using session to store state for a non-state web server can be problematic later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the

> $_SESSION['cd-dropdown']

since it was assigned.

it will only destroy if session_destroy is invoke.